# Google Photos Screensaver stopped working on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, screensaver, picasa

I have been running Google Photos Screensaver on Windows 8 without any trouble for the past month or so. In the past few days the screensaver failed to come on. Whatever I was working on was still there when I came back to my computer hours later.

I tried testing the preview button. The screen goes blank, something flickers and then it goes back to the desktop that was there before I hit preview. If I change the screen saver to something else (eg. Mystify) then preview works.

I am using Picasa 3.9.0

*The following failed to fix the problem*

I updated my nVidia GeForce GT 545 drivers.
I tried the preview with my mouse unplugged and then switched to my keyboard being unplugged.

Comment: Is it the latest Picasa version? Sorry, but haven't used Picasa in a while. Also, some background processes might be interfering

Comment: @PratyushNalam Yes, that is the latest version of Picasa. So would I have to kill half the background processes to see if it solves the problem and then half a half a half a half until I find the interfering background program?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't put it that way but how do you use your PC? Lots of windows open at a time? Or just a few? I used Picasa back in Windows 7. Haven't tested it in 8.